# Setting up headers with `scrbook`

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

How to setup `automark` in order to select a section if there is one and select the chapter instead of empty text if there is no section?

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,a5paper,7pt,openright,twoside=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[headsepline=true, autooneside = false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\lohead{}
\rohead{\rightmark}

\cofoot[]{}
\rofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\automark[section]{chapter}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test}
    \blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't show only a code snippet. Show  a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: Iam sorry, i edited the post above with a compilable code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```latex
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,
  a5paper,
  fontsize=7pt,% changed!
  %openright,% default
  %twoside=true% default
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[headsepline=true,
  %autooneside = false% not needed with the default twoside=true
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\AfterTOCHead{\pagestyle{plain}}
\AfterStartingTOC{\clearpage}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext[20]
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user211673 Did my answer solve your issue? Then you can vote it up and maybe accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want:

```
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{section}
```

Comment: Thank you, this removes the problem with the empty head, but now only sections are displayed instead of the chapter...